# Accelerometer too noisy

Tags: python, robotics

I am working on a group project for building a robot and we are trying to implement an accelerometer that triggers an alarm if the robot is picked up/pushed on the way. Right now our accelerometer is very noisy and not very reliable. Could someone point me in the right direction on how to fix this?
Current code:

```
 def accel_alarm(self):
        cur_accel = self.read_smooth_accel()
        accel_x, accel_y, accel_z = cur_accel
        base_x, base_y, base_z = (-32, 31, 1075)  # values when robot is static
        if abs(accel_x - base_x) > 350 or abs(
                accel_y - base_y) > 350 or abs(accel_z - base_z) > 350:
            if not (self.alarm):
                self.send_alarm()
                self.alarm = True
                print(
                    "[accel_alarm] ALARM STATE " + str(accel_x) + " X " + str(
                        accel_y) + " Y  " + str(accel_z) + " Z")

    # Smooth accelerometer output by taking the average of the last n values
    # where n = len(self.accel_data)
    def read_smooth_accel(self):
        cur_accel, _ = self.accel.read()
        self.accel_data.pop()
        self.accel_data.appendleft(cur_accel)
        # For the first len(accel_data) values the average is not
        # representative - just return current value
        if [0, 0, 0] in self.accel_data:
            return cur_accel

        av_accel = [sum(i) / float(len(i)) for i in zip(*self.accel_data)]
        return av_accel
```

The second method is trying to tackle the noisiness but it is still not very nice...

Comment: If your **hardware** is to noisy, why try to solve it with software? I'm suspecting your definition is a bit off when you say "noisy" tho, could you elaborate and explain why it's noisy and how you've noticed it?

Comment: you could implement some kind of mulitsampling - the accelerometer could wait for more than one consecutive positive signal (e.g. record last 3 results and if all of them are True, send True) or a part of the group being positive (e.g. record last 6 results and if 3 or more of them are True send True)

Comment: Basically, when it is turned on now and the robot is even static, it prints out the coordinates to the console every millisecond. We want to try to reduce the number of outputs to only appear when the robot moves more than 10cm in direction.

Comment: Did you calculate the bias or offset values of the sensor? Why did you choose static values as (-32, 31, 1075) and 350 for threshold?